# Deploying Quarkus Apps with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, quarkus

I'm trying to deploy an [example Quarkus app](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/rest-json-quickstart) with Kubernetes. Everything is fine when i run it in `dev` mode as `mvn quarkus:dev -Dquarkus.http.port=8080`. But when i deploy and go to the endpoint `localhost/rest-json` it says `RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://rest-json-http/`. i'm using `ingress-nginx`. What am i missing? Is there anything wrong with the k8s manifests?

Here is my `application.yml`:

```yaml
quarkus:
  http:
    cors:
      ~: true
    root-path: /rest-json
```

`deployment.yml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rest-json
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: rest-json
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rest-json
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rest-json
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: rest-json
          image: quarkus/rest-json-jvm:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

`service.yml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rest-json-http
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      name: http
  selector:
    app: rest-json
```

`ingress.yml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rest-json-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "rest-json-http"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /rest-json
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: rest-json-http
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Here is repo to reproduce [github.com/miador/rest-json-quickstart](http://Here%20is%20repo%20to%20reproduce%20github.com/miador/rest-json-quickstart)

Comment: Did you create those manifests on your own or did Quarkus do it for you? Another question, do things work without the `root-path`?

Comment: Yes i created them on my own. I also tried without `root-path` but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Try adding the `quarkus-kubernetes` extension and compare your manifests to what `target/kubernetes/kubernetes.yaml` has

Comment: With your ingress the path `/rest-json` will be rewritten to `/` thanks to the rewrite target annotation. Can you try with removing the Quarkus root path ?

Comment: @geoand i already compared with the auto-generated and the only difference i saw the service was `ClusterIP`, even the ports were same. Can it be the ingress?

Comment: @loicmathieu tried, didn't work.

Comment: [Here](https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-kubernetes) it says `Applications deployed to Kubernetes won’t be accessed via a Kubernetes Ingress, but rather as a NodePort Service.` Is it just by default or we can't use ingress at all?

Comment: Also i did type `quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.expose` as `true` but nothing has changed.

Comment: I haven't worked with the ngix ingress so I can't really say for sure

Comment: I do use the nginx ingress. And the section on the guide just describe what the guide try to achieve, there is no issue with ingress and Quarkys. It's totally separated concept.
Can you try with removing the `upstream-vhost` annotation on your ingress and set the host to `rest-json-http` instead ?

Comment: It returns `Resource not found`

Comment: Do you have a running example? Maybe a git repo that i can have a look?

Comment: Hi, I'd reckon you could try to set the `Ingress` path to: `/` and delete the annotations. That would make all of the requests with their full paths go to the `rest-json-http` `Service`. Please try it and tell what's the outcome. Also if you could add a reproducible example as user miador pointed, it could be easier to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: `RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://rest-json-http/` same error.

Comment: Here is repo to reproduce https://github.com/miador/rest-json-quickstart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
```

and this:

```
- path: /rest-json/(.+)
```

and then access: http://localhost/rest-json/fruits.html

[Here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/) you can see more about ingress path matching.

Comment: Wow! I didn't think about matchmaking. Thanks! That worked like a charm.